# selenium python get weird

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

This code is meant to scrape  google translate, I use selenium to **scrape** every possible translation for a given word.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\Tutorial\Driver\chromedriver.exe")

words = ['girl', 'cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'man']
for word in words:
    driver.get("https://translate.google.com.eg/?hl=en&tab=wT#en/fr/" + word)

translations = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gt-baf-word-clickable')

for text in translations:
    print(text.text)
```

And the thing is the **scraper** just do the job for the first word only.

Comment: yoiu have wrong indentions - `translations` and second `for` is not inside first `for` - so it is executed only for one word.

Comment: do you get error when you run it in console/terminal ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: @furas there is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code works for me if I use correct indentions and add `time.sleep(1)` so browser has time to load page. If I don't use `time.sleep(1)` then it can't find element and I get error message.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\Tutorial\Driver\chromedriver.exe")

words = ['girl', 'cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'man']
for word in words:
    driver.get("https://translate.google.com.eg/?hl=en&tab=wT#en/fr/" + word)
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        translations = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gt-baf-word-clickable')

        for text in translations:
            print(text.text)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Tested on Linux Mint 18 / Python 3.6.2 / Selenium 3.6.0

Comment: BTW: selenium has own method to wait till page is read to get data but I never remeber its full name - something with `wait`.